# How to recursively un-gzip all my files?

Tags: tar, gzip

I accidentally `gzip`'d all my files in a directory, and in all of its subdirectories. All the files in the subdirectories are now replaced with a zipped one (`.gz` extension). For example `example.txt` is now `example.txt.gz`

Is it possible to reverse this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `gzip` and `gunzip` support use of the `-r` option for recursive operation.

```
gunzip -r /directory/
```

Should change all of your files back to their previous format.

Comment: Shoot, I was too late! Good answer, though.